# Compilation error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator^'

Tags: arduino

I try to compile these lines but it says Compilation error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator^'

```
 float a=3.75;
  float b=6.0;
  float c=-3.0;
  float negRoot=(-b-sqrt(b^2-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);
  float posRoot=(-b+sqrt(b^2-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);
```

I tried putting periods after all the numbers in it.

Comment: `^` does not mean exponentiation in C.  Just use `b*b`.

Comment: Arduino is programmed in C++, not C btw, removed the tag

Comment: also why do you think adding periods after all the numbers would help? the error messag tells you that you cannot use two floats with a binary operator. that would be the moment where you should either google the error message or at least find out what a binary operator ^ is. make sure you know what you're dealing with. don't use any operator based on a guess. find out what it does and how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use the ^ operator, which is the bitwise exclusive OR operator.

C does not have a built-in operator for exponentiation. But the standard library provide some functions:

```
   #include <math.h>

   double pow(double x, double y);
   float powf(float x, float y);
   long double powl(long double x, long double y);
```

Or as @Steve Summit suggests, just use `x * x`.

Comment: But you don't want to use `pow` for simple squaring, either.

Comment: @SteveSummit Touché.